# How to plot keras activation functions in a notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, activation-function

I wanted to plot all Keras activation functions but some of them are not working. i.e. `linear` throws an error:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'eval'

which is weird. How can I plot the rest of my activation functions?

```
points = 100
zeros = np.zeros((points,1))

df = pd.DataFrame({"activation": np.linspace(-1.2,1.2,points)})
df["softmax"] = K.eval(activations.elu(df["activation"]))
#df["linear"] = K.eval(activations.linear(df["activation"]))
df["tanh"] = K.eval(activations.tanh(df["activation"]))
df["sigmoid"] = K.eval(activations.sigmoid(df["activation"]))
df["relu"] = K.eval(activations.relu(df["activation"]))
#df["hard_sigmoid"] = K.eval(activations.hard_sigmoid(df["activation"]))
#df["exponential"] = K.eval(activations.exponential(df["activation"]))
df["softsign"] = K.eval(activations.softsign(df["activation"]))
df["softplus"] = K.eval(activations.softplus(df["activation"]))
#df["selu"] = K.eval(activations.selu(df["activation"]))
df["elu"] = K.eval(activations.elu(df["activation"]))

df.plot(x="activation", figsize=(15,15))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `linear` activation returns the input without any modifications:

```
def linear(x):
    """Linear (i.e. identity) activation function.
    """
    return x
```

Since you are passing a Pandas Series as input, the same Pandas Series will be returned and therefore you don't need to use `K.eval()`:

```
df["linear"] = activations.linear(df["activation"])
```

As for the `selu` activation, you need to reshape the input to `(n_samples, n_output)`:

```
df["selu"] = K.eval(activations.selu(df["activation"].values.reshape(-1,1)))
```

And as for the `hard_sigmoid` activation, its input should be explicitly a Tensor which you can create using `K.variable()`:

```
df["hard_sigmoid"] = K.eval(activations.hard_sigmoid(K.variable(df["activation"].values)))
```

Further, `exponential` activation works as you have written and there is no need for modifications.