# Plotting a new activation function defined using an existing one from Keras

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, activation-function

Is it possible to plot an activation function that I define using an already existing activation from Keras? I tried doing it simply like this:

```py
import keras
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define swish activation:
def swish(x):
    return K.sigmoid(x) * x

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)

plt.plot(x, swish(x))
plt.show()
```

but the above code produces an error: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'`.

I've noticed this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53091121/how-to-plot-keras-activation-functions-in-a-notebook) but I couldn't adjust it to my need. I also tried playing with the `.eval()` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/how-can-i-convert-a-tensor-into-a-numpy-array-in-tensorflow) but also without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also tried playing with the `.eval()` like suggested here but also without success.

How did you use it? This should work:

```
plt.plot(x, K.eval(swish(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks, even simpler solution. What I tried was to place `eval()` like this: `K.eval(sigmoid(x)) * x` inside the function definition. I actually don't know why it doesn't work, the error is: `NameError: name 'sigmoid' is not defined`.

Comment: @camillejr Of course it should not work, because `sigmoid` is defined inside backend module, so you must write: `K.eval(K.sigmoid(x)) * x`

Answer (score 1):

You need a session to evaluate:

```
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)

with tf.Session().as_default():
    y = swish(x).eval()

plt.plot(x, y)
```